# Facebook-ios-sdk dialog disappears immediately

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tabs

I am creating an iphone app with 5 tabs, each tab has a root view controller and I push view controllers on each root view. When I show a facebook dialog from the root view controller, it shows with no problem. However, when I try to show it from the pushed view controller, the dialog will just show and disappear immediately without even loading the page requested. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=90822#p319064

the jist: in FBDialog.m, change

```
if (!window) {
window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

to

```
window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I had this problem in iOS 4 but not iOS 5, what a nightmare. In my case a UIAlert overlay window was the key window at the time when FB got to this code, so commenting the if clause worked for me too.